# Can't create new user using Parse 1.7.2 and Facebook SDK 4.1 in Xcode using Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

I've linked my app to both the Facebook SDK and Parse, but now I'm trying to integrate Facebook's login with Parse but keep running into issues. My current issue is that the app runs, but when I press the FBSDKLoginButton, it will go to safari and ask for permissions (as it should), but then when pressing okay, it simply returns to the app's login screen like nothing happened and does not perform the segue to the rest of the app. I also checked Parse and it did not create a new PFUser. I will post the code I think may be relevant from my LoginViewController below (that means the code will be missing sections like my viewDidLoad for it has nothing in it that affects the login process):

```
import UIKit
import Parse
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate {
    func onRegister(loginViewController : LoginViewController)
    func onFacebookLogin(loginViewController : LoginViewController)
    func onLogin(loginViewController : LoginViewController)
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func onFacebookLogin(sender: AnyObject?) {

    // Set permissions required from the facebook user account
    let permissions = [ "user_about_me", "user_relationships", "user_location", "user_birthday", "public_profile", "user_friends", "user_email", "user_gender"]

    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let user = user {
            if user.isNew {
                println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!")
                self.loadData()
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: self)
            } else {
                println("User logged in through Facebook!")
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: self)
            }
            if self.delegate != nil {
                self.delegate!.onFacebookLogin(self)
            }
        } else {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.")
        }
    })
}

func loadData(){
    let request:FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest()
    request.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection:FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil{
            if let dict = result as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                let name:String = dict["first_name"] as AnyObject? as! String
                let facebookID:String = dict["id"] as AnyObject? as! String
                let email:String = dict["email"] as AnyObject? as! String
                let birthday:String = dict["birthday"] as AnyObject? as! String
                let gender:String = dict["gender"] as AnyObject? as! String

                let hostCount:Int = 0
                let attendCount:Int = 0

                let pictureURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookID)/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1"

                var URLRequest = NSURL(string: pictureURL)
                var URLRequestNeeded = NSURLRequest(URL: URLRequest!)


                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(URLRequestNeeded, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!,data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        var picture = PFFile(data: data)
                        PFUser.currentUser()!.setObject(picture, forKey: "profilePicture")
                        PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
                    }
                    else {
                        println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
                PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
                PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
                PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(birthday, forKey: "birthday")
                PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(gender, forKey: "gender")
                PFUser.currentUser()!.setValue(hostCount, forKey: "hostCount")
                PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating to Parse 1.7.4 and deleting the old PFFacebookUtils Framework (keeping the PFFacebookUtilsV4) seems to have fixed the problem by itself! I hope this answer helps other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution, hope it helps you. If you have a question on it, I can answer :)

```
func notLoggedIn() -> Bool {
    let user = PFUser.currentUser()
    // here I assume that a user must be linked to Facebook
    return user == nil || !PFFacebookUtils.isLinkedWithUser(user)
}

func loggedIn() -> Bool {
    return !notLoggedIn()
}

func performNewUser(){

    if notLoggedIn() {
        return
    }
    let user = PFUser.currentUser() // Won't be nil because is logged in
    // RETURN IF WE ALREADY HAVE A USERNAME AND FBID (note that we check the fbId because Parse automatically fills in the username with random numbers)
    if let fbId = user["fbId"] as? String {
        if !fbId.isEmpty {
            displayAlert("Erreur", error: "Il existe déjà un utilisateur avec ce compte Facebook")
            println("we already have a username and fbId -> return")
            return
        }
    }
    // REQUEST TO FACEBOOK
    println("performing request to FB for username and IDF...")
    if let session = PFFacebookUtils.session() {
        if session.isOpen {
            println("session is open")
            FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler({ (connection: FBRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                println("done me request")
                if error != nil {
                    println("facebook me request - error is not nil :(")
                } else {
                    println("facebook me request - error is nil :)")
                    println(result)
                    println(result.name)
                    println(result.objectID)
                    // Save to Parse:
                    var FBSession = PFFacebookUtils.session()
                    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
                    var userToSave = PFObject(className: "Utilisateurs")
                    var accessToken = FBSession.accessTokenData.accessToken
                    let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token="+accessToken)
                    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)


                    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(urlRequest, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
                        response, data, error in

                        let image = UIImage(data: data)
                        currentUser["image"] = data
                        currentUser.save()                        
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("connexionApplicationInscriptionViaFacebook", sender: self)

                    })


                    let firstName = result["first_name"] as String
                    let status = "Client"
                    currentUser.username = result["last_name"] as String
                    currentUser.email = result.email

                    userToSave.setObject(currentUser.username, forKey: "nom")
                    userToSave.setObject(currentUser.username, forKey: "username")
                    userToSave.setObject(firstName, forKey: "prenom")
                    userToSave.setObject(status, forKey: "status")

                    currentUser.setValue(self.tfPrenom.text, forKey: "name")
                    currentUser.setValue(result.objectID, forKey: "fbId")
                    currentUser.saveEventually() // Always use saveEventually if you want to be sure that the save will succeed
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, Bertrand! I just tried this method, but I'm getting two errors: one at the line that says "if let fbId = user["fbId"] as? String {" stating "'String?' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'". The other error is on the line with "if let session = PFFacebookUtils.session() {" which states "'PFFacebookUtils.Type' does not have a member named 'session'"

Comment: Are you using the newest versions of Parse and Facebook SDK?

Comment: Argh! im' using Xcode 6.2 and  parse 1.6.4, the older version of parse, i'm so sorry, I didn't see that you are using the newest version :/

Comment: Fo the first error it seems to be an evolution of casting to string, maybe you have to declare fbid before like this : var fbid:String = ""
And for "session" it was a public api in PFFacebookUtils.h : ( /*!
 @abstract Gets the Facebook session for the current user.
 */
+ (PF_NULLABLE FBSession *)session;
)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Did you use this in an IBAction for a UIButton or a FBSDKLoginButton?

Comment: Yes, i call this function in an IBAction, when my user want to log in with a new account :)